Cannot import name 'DatasetFilter' from 'huggingface_hub'
Cannot import name 'DatasetFilter' from 'huggingface_hub'
(/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/huggingface_hub/__init__.py)

Issue while using huggingface_hub

This is a known error for huggingface_hub (0.24.0)
huggingface_hub (0.24.0) was released on Jul 18, 2024

DatasetFilter has been deprecated since version 0.21.0 and will be removed in next version of huggingface_hub (0.24.0). This PR updates the code to get rid of DatasetFilter and use plain args instead.

https://github.com/huggingface/setfit/pull/527#issue-2309913178
For now try :
pip install huggingface_hub==0.23.5

https://github.com/huggingface/huggingface_hub/issues/2401#issuecomment-2238649765

The error is due to huggingface_hub 0.24.0 release,  #527 would solve it.
Either downgrade huggingface_hub version to 0.23.5:
pip uninstall -y huggingface_hub
pip install huggingface_hub==0.23.5

or install SetFit from source:
pip install git+https://github.com/Wauplin/setfit@dont-use-deprecated-dataset-filter

